# Java Refactoring of Exception Handling Best Practice

Tags: java, exception, refactoring

**Description:**
I am always told by people check all your parameters all the time which results in a lot of if checks and try catches.

**Question:**
In the code below I cleaned the code such that only method that handles the exception handling is at the root method that is exposed publicly and not in the refactored private helper methods. Is this practice ok?

I'm not handling exceptions closer to the methods they could occur in but the code is much cleaner.

**Code Notes:**

- Method validateInputs() not included.
- ParameterObject a is derived let say from parameters created through "someCode", it represents parameters I want to pass around. Anytime I have a need for more than 2 parameters i refactor those parameters to a parameter object.

Code:

```
public class UnderTest {

    public UnderTest() {}

    public boolean runWork(  String someValue ) throws CustomException
    {
        try
        {
            validateInputs();
            // someCode
            .
            .
            processWork(  ParameterObject a );
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            logError(e);
        }
    }

    private void processWork( ParameterObject a  )
    {
        Operation1( ParameterObject a  );
        Operation2( ParameterObject a  );
    }

    private void Operation1( ParameterObject a  )
    {
        // someCode
    }

    private void Operation2( ParameterObject a  )
    {
        // someCode
    }

    private void logError(Exception e)
    {    
        throw new CustomException(e,"Message");
    }        
}
```

Comment: "I am always told by people check all your parameters all the time which results in a lot of if checks and try catches."  It depends on your context, but in many cases you shouldn't be catching those exceptions at all -- they represent bugs elsewhere in your program, and an uncaught exception is the easiest way to tell your test suites to fail a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to check arguments when they enter the class by some public API. In private methods I check only by assertions or not at all. This implies that I trust my own class a bit more.

Comment: That's a good point on the assertions. If I am designing the class and use refactored helper private methods, the assertions should cover me if another programmer later came in and made one public and didn't properly validate the inputs. It will help prevent the programmer bug.

Answer (score 1):

I would opt for a bit of both. Validating inputs is always a good idea and libraries such as the [Apache commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) `Validate` class can make this easier. Generally speaking, an incorrect argument should cause a *runtime* exception (usually `IllegalArgumentException` or `NullPointerException`). How deeply you go into your private methods to do input validation is a matter of taste. Remember that the sooner you spot an invalid argument, the more helpful the error message is going to be.

Of course, this assumes you document your public facing APIs well (and ideally your internal methods too). Make it clear what is valid for your inputs.

Comment: Ya in my case I use a refactored param object, and pass it around a lot to the refactored private methods. Validating every time you enter the method just seems like a lot of code validation is occuring that shouldn't , especially like Heiko Schmitz above pointed out if you put in assertions. +1 for the apache commons-lang reference for validate. I will look into that.

Comment: @haju Just remember that assertions are [disabled by default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html#enable-disable).